# Display menu and pages of a newly created extension

Tags: extension, civicrm-buildkit, civix

I am working a new extension that i created throough civix. i have added some pages and some forms, how do i display the menu on the home page of the extension and navigate to the different pages and forms. when i install my extension and run it, i get this message:  Thank you for creating with WordPress.

Version 4.2.2

Comment: Are you really using CiviCRM version 4.2.2? That's super old, unsupported, and insecure, and I'm not surprised it doesn't work.

Comment: No, thats the version of wordpress not Civi, my civi is the latest version!

Comment: Please edit your question to say *exactly* what command you typed to generate the pages/forms.

Comment: civix generate:page Facebooksettings/facebooksettings for example

Comment: Pls edit your question to add details rather than commenting. Looks like you typed a path that doesn't start with civicrm? I don't think that's supported.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you modify a menu xml file you must clear CiviCRM's menu cache.

Go to **Administer > System Settings > Cleanup Caches & Update Paths** and click the **Cleanup Caches** button.

Comment: great, I have done that but I stiil get the same information, its like my menu xml file is not been read or may be am not doing it correctly. But I just want to access a basic page i created after creating the extension.This should not be so difficult and hidden I think.

Comment: Normally it isn't difficult. If you use the "[civix generate:page](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension#CreateaModuleExtension-Addabasicwebpage)" command and clear your cache, it will become available immediately. Note the web path should always start with "civicrm".

Comment: Thanks @Coleman for the tips i succeded with this problem.